# How should I program this complex grid?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, uicollectionview

I have a grid that has 2 - 4 clusters of information. Please see the attached -- very -- rough image mockup.

I'd appreciate ideas on a good way to program this. The data source is a Json feed that will be updated frequently (every minute). Each cluster may be 2 or more of these batches. I was thinking UITableView, UICollectionView, or, make a custom view.!

[image]

Comment: I used a tableview doing this, in iOS8, it is a little more work to achieve a grouped tableview like the answer below, I ended up drawing the cells.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a grouped table view may be the way to go. The "Title 1" and "Title 2" would be section headers, with the rows below them representing the detail lines.

The detail lines would then be custom table view cells.

A dated, but still relevant example:

[image: Grouped UITableView]

Comment: You should add that as a new answer along with your reasoning. I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: hmm. I like just about anything Nick Lockwood has developed so I'll give it a good look. Thanks.

Comment: All close but no cigars.. The trouble with grouped table views  is that they get complicated when each line (Cupertino, Glenda;e, etc) are three or four fields/cells.. FXForms is really a solution for developing input forms, and does nor, as far as I can tell, provide a grid interface. More ideas welcome or I will need to go as gabbler suggests, and roll my own.